# how to position a css sprite as background for another class

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

Sorry if the layout of the question seems weird, I've wrote this question now for about 10 times over and over again in this editor, resulting always in getting an error message "unformatted code found etc." - so I removed all the code and placed picture examples. (2 hours for a simple question)

---

Hello folks!
I do have a **.png image**, containing **several icons** that works as **CSS Sprite**.
The creation of each CSS class for that is no problem as I use a generator for that. (works like a charm)
The problem is, that I want to use, for example: The created `.iconInfo_32` class, as `background` property for **another** css class.

## What I want to achive?

Simple said, a custom css - messagebox, with an icon on the left side.
The icon itself is in original a sprite containing multiple icons.
That's where the problem starts.

### What I have

#### The Icons

[image: icons] (thats one PNG)

#### The Icon I want to use

[image: icons]

#### How the result should look like

[image: right]

#### How it actually looks

[image: right]

#### Use another div, in a div

Yes, that would work - but I'd like to have "one" css class, without the need to put always a div, into another div, say where the position should be and so on - also I had problems with the position of the div.

I've provided a source example, hopefully this will help being able to understand my question and my goal.
Excuse me if the layout of my question is unusual and unpleasent, I would have done it in another way, but the editor just won't let me

## Source

#### HTML

```
<div class="warning_without_sprite">
    This is a DIV container<br />
    showing an error message with the use of 'close_32.png' as Icon. (No Sprite)
</div><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="warning_with_sprite">
    This is a DIV container<br />
    showing an error message with the use of 'icons.png' as Icon. (Sprite)
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
  .iconInfo_32 { width: 32px; height: 32px; background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat -0px -0px; }
  .iconOk_32 { width: 32px; height: 32px; background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat -32px -0px; }
  .iconAdd_32 { width: 32px; height: 32px; background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat -64px -0px; }
  .iconClose_2_32 { width: 32px; height: 32px; background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat -96px -0px; }
  .iconClose_32 { width: 32px; height: 32px; background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat -128px -0px; }
  .iconDelete_32 { width: 32px; height: 32px; background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat -160px -0px; }
  .iconDownload_32 { width: 32px; height: 32px; background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat -192px -0px; }
  .iconHelp_32 { width: 32px; height: 32px; background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat -224px -0px; }

.warning_without_sprite {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 10px center;
float:left;
color: #D8000C;
background-color: #FFBABA;
background-image: url('images/close_32.png');
}
.warning_with_sprite {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 10px center;
float:left;
color: #D8000C;
background: #FFBABA url('images/icons.png') no-repeat -128px -0px;
}
</style>
```

[>> Download as RAR. <<](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39145345/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.rar)

Comment: Please show your HTML/CSS in your question, not as a download.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll try to provide it again, hopefully this time successfully without getting a "your question contains unformatted code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've set it as a background-image across the whole `<div>` element and because the sprite contains multiple images it will show them all. You can't specify how much of that sprite to show.

You'll have to insert a `<span>` element into your `<div>`. This will allow you to specify the size of the span and position it relative to your div container.

```
<div class="warning">
    <span class="warning_with_sprite"></span>
    This is a DIV container<br />
    showing an error message with the use of 'icons.png' as Icon. (Sprite)
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.warning_with_sprite {
    position:absolute; left:16px; top:16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    width:20px; height:20px; 
    background: url('http://i5.minus.com/id1CYq.png') no-repeat -133px -2px;
}
.warning { 
    float:left;
    color: #D8000C;
    border: 1px solid;
    position:relative;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px; 
    background: #FFBABA; 
}
```

See a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/csE5B/)

**Note: you'll have to change the image back to your sprite and the top, left, height and width properties will have to change inline with your requirements**

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, one thing that remains is the question if its possible to set the icon to valign="middle" - so that it will stay in the middle? (with pure CSS)

Comment: @user2615607 No, you can't. You can set it to stay in the middle by using position: absolute; and specifying the top and left co-ordinates

Comment: Thanks for your time! So I'll use javascript, as the text content is dynamic and so on the height.

Comment: @user2615607 If the text is dynamic you could use top:50%; margin-top:-imageHeight (I don't know how tall your image is, but that's static so use that)

Comment: Thanks for the hint again, I used "-(imageHeight / 2)", works like a charm now